# How to open URL with Uri upon results = keyword?

Tags: java, if-statement, web

Here is the code:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if results = "google" (Uri.parse(url));
    if (requestCode == check && resultCode == RESULT_OK){

        ArrayList<String> results = data.getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
        lv.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, results));
        }

    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
} }
```

I need the results IF = "keyword" to open website, for now in quotes until I add database.

Comment: `if results = "google" (Uri.parse(url));`?? Does this even compile? Also, don't use `=` or `==` to compare Strings. Use the `equals(...)` or `equalsIgnoreCase(...)` methods.

Comment: I think i got the first part figured out ... the IF portion.

Comment: if (RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS == "google")

Comment: Now it's an answer. Again, don't use `==`.

Comment: How about this: if (RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS equals "google"){
   System.out.println("THIS IS A TEST!");
  }

Comment: See my answer below. It shows how to use the equals or equalsIgnoreCase methods.

Comment: Thank you VERY much. =) My real concern is how to open the browser with URL next.Can u suggest proper code for the //do something to open browser with url ??

Comment: Opening a browser is OS and OS-setup dependent. One way is as shown here: [Open a Browser in Java](http://www.mkyong.com/java/open-browser-in-java-windows-or-linux/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Again, don't use `==` to compare Strings. I'm not sure how to convince you of this fact, but it will often cause unexpected errors in your program. Again, use `String#equals(...)` or `String#equalsIgnoreCase(...)` methods.

Please understand that == checks if the two *objects* are the same which is not what you're interested in. The methods on the other hand check if the two Strings have the same characters in the same order, and that's what matters here.  So instead of

```
if (fu == "bar") {
  // do something
}
```

do,

```
if (fu.equals("bar")) {
  // do something
}
```

or,

```
if (fu.equalsIgnoreCase("bar")) {
  // do something
}
```

Comment: Ok I think I got it: if (RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS.equals ("google")){
   System.out.println("THIS IS A TEST!");